# shared_ptr refcounter implementation thead safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

This is the implementation of `shared_ptr` from VisualStudio 2017

MSDN states that refcounting block is thread safe.
I wonder, what if in thread1 we check rep for null (`if (_Other._Rep) //1`),
then thread2 check rep for null, decrese refcounter to 0 and call `_Destroy();`
after that thread1 tryes to increment deleted ref counter. Isn't it a problem or where I have misunderstanding?

```
void _Copy_construct_from(const shared_ptr<_Ty2>& _Other)
{   // implement shared_ptr's (converting) copy ctor
    if (_Other._Rep) //1
    {
        _Other._Rep->_Incref();
    }

    _Ptr = _Other._Ptr;
    _Rep = _Other._Rep;
}

void _Decref()
  { // decrement reference count
    if (_Rep) //2
    {
        _Rep->_Decref(); //3
    }
  }

void _Decref()
{   // decrement use count
    if (_MT_DECR(_Uses) == 0)
    {   // destroy managed resource, decrement weak reference count
        _Destroy();
        _Decwref();
    }
}
```

update:

```
 thread1: ctor (_Copy_construct_from)
  thread1: if (_Other._Rep) 
  thread2 _Decref
  thread2 _Rep->_Decref();
  thread2 _Destroy();
  thread1 _Other._Rep->_Incref(); // but object is already destroed
```

Comment: Can you indicate with some pseudo-code what order of events you think can cause this issue? Maybe (I'm not sure), you didn't consider the fact that a shared_ptr can't be destroyed while anything is making a copy of it. If that somehow happens, you have different issues with access to data that shared between threads but where access is not being synchronized correctly.

Comment: If you're making a copy, there exists an object that you are copying from.  That itself stops the pointer from being destroyed out from under you.

Comment: actualy it's not, first it check's if rep is not null after that it call's increment, but if I understand correctly in between object can be destroed from another thread. See code in my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are showing in the first block is part of the copying or converting constructor, e.g. you are calling something along the line of:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> some_shared_ptr = some_other_shared_ptr;
```

When the thread executes the line either `some_other_shared_ptr` is not currently owning any object or it is owning an object. If it is owning an object, then it will keep owning the object during the execution of that statement. Therefore the reference count of the owned object is at least one and cannot become zero and the object will not be destroyed while the statement executes.

If another thread destroys or modifies (e.g. by reseting it) the `some_other_shared_ptr` object itself potentially while the other thread executes the statement, then the program has a data race and undefined behavior. The `shared_ptr` object itself is not atomic (and even if it were, destroying it potentially before accessing it in another thread would cause undefined behavior). It is only thread safe in the sense that additional owning copies can be made and destroyed freely across threads without causing data races, the reference count to the owned object becoming inconsistent or the object being destroyed multiple times.